# can you suggest me courses to start DSP?

Tags: speech-processing

I'm a cs student who's totally 100 % new to DSP can you recommend me math , physics and all the required courses so i can understand DSP better?
thank you 
and also can you recommend some courses / books so i can study DSP?

Comment: I was kind of surprised you had a previous question that was actually already marked a duplicate of the answer above. Instead of asking the same question again, you should have explained what was not sufficient and which questions were left open after reading that question and its answers!